# Update table from another table throught intermediate table Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the next table setup, two tables related by an intermediate table, like this:

Client

```
| client_id | ...|field_X |
| 1         | ...|value1  |
| 2         | ...|value2  |
| 3         | ...|value3  |
```

Project

```
| project_id | ...|field_X |
| 1          | ...|        |
| 2          | ...|        |
| 3          | ...|        |
| 4          | ...|        |
| 5          | ...|        |
| 6          | ...|        |
| 7          | ...|        |
```

client_project

```
| client_id | project_id|
|     1     |      2    |
|     1     |      3    |
|     2     |      4    |
|     2     |      5    |
|     3     |      6    |
|     3     |      7    |
```

The field_x in the table project is new and i have to fill it with the data from  table client to get approximately something like this:

Project

```
| project_id | ...|field_X |
| 1          | ...|        |
| 2          | ...|value1  |
| 3          | ...|value1  |
| 4          | ...|value2  |
| 5          | ...|value2  |
| 6          | ...|value3  |
| 7          | ...|value3  |
```

i dont know hot to deal with the intermediate table. i have tried this code but it doesnt work.

```
INSERT INTO project  
(field_x)

(select field_x
from 
 client_project
  inner join
 client
  where client_project.client_id = client.client_id 
 );
```

I have the idea of what i have to do but i am not able to translate it  into a sql command because of the intermeditate table.Could someone explain how to deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already have all entries in the `project` table but they're missing the Field_X property? So what you need is an update, not an insert

```
UPDATE project p, client c, project_client pc SET p.Field_X=c.Field_X WHERE p.ID=pc.ProjectID AND c.ID=pc.ClientID
```

However, be advised that having the same data in two places is not a good practise; if possible always put one fact in only one place.

Comment: Indeed, all entries in the proyect table are already in.when i manage to copy the data i will erase the field from client